# How do I transfer variable information from one prefab to another?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two prefabs.
1) FoodItem
2) Consumer

```
public class ItemController{
    //Item Details
    public float price;
    public float eatingTime;
}
```

Ofter the two object of connect triggered the customer needs to "eat"  for a period of time.  Once they have eaten then they pay.  The pay needs to update the score.

```
public class CharacterControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    //CustomerDetails
    if(time == eatingTime){
    Score = Score + price;
    UpdateScore();
    }
}

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public float Score;
    public Text scoreText;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        scoreText.text = "0";
    }

    public void UpdateScore()
    {
        scoreText.text = Score.ToString("2");
    }
}
```

I have tried connecting the scripts, but once the prefab has been created it drops the script, so the score doesn't work.

I tried doing a static variable, however I ran into issues.  Odds are I messed up how it is suppose to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that you could do, but the best thing is probably to do something like this:

```
public class CharacterControl
{

    void Update()
    {
        GameObject.FindGameObjectByTag("Tag-of-scoremanager-").GetComponent <ScoreManager> ().Score += price;


    }
}
```

Another way is for example to include the Score manager as an inspector property, like so:

```
ScoreManager manager;
```

and then drag and drop the score manager prefab into the inspector,
and then to increment it simply do:

```
manager.Score += price;
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: I got it to work!  I put the Score as a static public float Score, which let me use what you mentioned.  Then I just put the scoreTxext in an Update().  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)